Must name on absentee ballot match registration?
In Vermont, US, in cases where the voter writes the name on the absentee ballot, is it necessary that the name exactly match the name on the town or city checklist? (In Vermont being on the checklist is equivalent to being registered to vote. I know election officials check that a signature is present on the absentee ballot, but no specimen signatures are available to see if they match.)
An example where the voter would write the voter's name on the absentee ballot envelope or information page is the federal mail absentee ballot

No, within reason.
Because absentee ballot/ballot requests include mailing/return address and other information, because Vermont requires that all registered voters on the checklist have a single address of residence, and because the Clerk has authority to add names to the checklist in Vermont in the absence of the availability of BCA personnel when there's a doubt, if the name/address pair is a sufficient match that a reasonable person can conclude that the ballot purports to originate from the same person as is listed on the checklist, they can accept the vote and mark you as having voted - possibly causing an update to the checklist to match the most recently submitted name.
If, for whatever reason, they are unable to establish that match then the ballot is considered defective, triggering an automatic alert to the person who submitted the vote

When an early or absentee voter is not legally qualified to vote, or has voted in person, or if the certificate on the voted ballot envelope is not signed, or the voted ballot is not in the voted ballot envelope, or, in the case of a primary vote, the early or absentee voter has failed to return the unvoted primary ballots, the envelope must be marked “defective”. The voter will be notified that the return of their ballot was defective, within three days of the clerk receiving it, and the voter will have an opportunity to correct the error and have their ballot counted.

In the event that the name is either too common, or too wildly varying from the checklist you'll be told as much and offered the chance to establish your qualification to vote and cure the defect.  Round trip mailing times being what they are, you should know within a week of having submitted your vote, but either way once you receive the notice that it was found to be defective, so long as you act swiftly about it, you should have the ability to correct the issues and get your vote counted.

Thank you for the link to the "Election Procedures 2024" booklet.
